# Find nearest set from list of integers stored in database

Tags: algorithm, sqlite

I would like to find the nearest or the same set of integers as stored in a database table.
Stored list length is variable from 0..10, order of elements is important.

For instance:

```
1:[1234, 2345, 5463, 1235]
2:[2355, 5463, 1235]
3:[123, 1234, 1235, 5463, 3443]
```

If I have a new set like: `[1235, 5463]`, I would like to find the nearest or matching set. In this case `3:[123, 1234, 1235, 5463, 3443]`.

Because the sets are stored in a database I was considering of transforming the lists into a hashed value, and then sort it according to calculated hash from given set.

It doesn't have to be perferct, If I can find the most suitable result in the first records I'm fine.

What would be the best hashing method to achive this?

Or are there any other suitable solutions.

Comment: Nearest, is the set that has the most same elements in the same order.

Comment: Do the elements have to be consecutive (i.e nearest = longest common substring)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in nearest you really meant "longest common substring" (LCS), then hashing will not help you - you really need to compute the LCS of your query with each of the elements of your database (or at least the top few ones, as you've mentioned).

The best way to do that is by dynamic programming. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) for the full details of that.